# Make Linq function more generic parameters

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, .net-core

How do I generalize this function? I want `Name` property to be variable, and have function accept, replace the persons class with any class.

```
// Filtering logic  
Func<SampleFilterModel, IEnumerable<Person>> filterData = (filterModel) =>  
{  
    return persons.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(filterModel.Term ?? String.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))  
       .Skip((filterModel.Page-1) * filter.Limit)  
       .Take(filterModel.Limit);  
};
```

Other items:

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = new List<Person>() {
    new Person() { Name = "Laura Callahan", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1958-01-09"), Email = "laura.callahan@test.com" },
    new Person() { Name = "Anne Dodsworth", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1966-01-27"), Email = "anne.dodsworth@test.com" }
};

public class SampleFilterModel
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }

    public SampleFilterModel()
    {
        this.Page = 1;
        this.Limit = 3;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, this.GetType());
    }
}
```

Current attempt, trying to modify/rework as needed:

giving some problems/errors:

1. Do I have to declare all variables as static?
2. Getting error message:

   > 'T' does not contain a definition for 'propertyInfo' and no accessible extension method 'propertyInfo' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:

```
public class Filterclass<T> where T : class
{
    public static string ColumnName;
    public static SampleFilterModel filter = new SampleFilterModel();
    public static IEnumerable<T> input;

    public Func<SampleFilterModel, IEnumerable<T>> filterData = (filterModel) =>
    {
        var propertyInfo = input.GetType().GetProperty(ColumnName);

        return input.Where(p => p.propertyInfo.StartsWith(filterModel.Term ?? String.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Skip((filterModel.Page - 1) * filter.Limit)
        .Take(filterModel.Limit);
    };
}
```

Comment: hi @VidmantasBlazevicius trying to figure out, not sure if comment brings any increase in value, starting to program few months ago, its also good practice for person who asked question to show current attempt https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223480/to-flag-or-not-to-flag-question-that-dont-show-own-effort  , thank you anyway

Comment: Read up on linq expression tress and dynamically building linq expressions.

Comment: Unless you are using some kind of contract that guarantees that the Name property is there, you will have to use reflection and dynamic expressions.

Comment: hi @Nkosi correct, trying to implement it here, var propertyInfo = input.GetType().GetProperty(ColumnName);

Comment: Are you just trying to get the value from `propertyInfo`? Should you not be using this: `Where(p => p.GetValue(input).StartsWith...` ?

Comment: trying to get member name, given a variable

Comment: @MattSmith I get that but if you are setting `ColumnName` to "Name" then `propertyInfo.GetValue(input)` will get you the name value for the given `input`. I included `p.` in my previous comment but it shouldn't have. Try this `propertyInfo.GetValue(p).ToString().StartsWith...`

Comment: @MattSmith another issue you have is that you are getting calling `input.GetType()` which is an `IEnumerable`. You should use `var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(ColumnName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the rest of the question does not make much sense to me, the part about trying to make a generic function would require building up a predicate for the `Where` call

Review the comments included to get an example of how to build up the lambda expression used for the predicate

```
public static class Filterclass {
    static readonly MethodInfo startsWith = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(System.StringComparison) });

    public static IEnumerable<T> FilterData<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, string columnName, FilterModel filterModel) where T : class {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(columnName);
        //T p =>
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        //T p => p.ColumnName
        var name = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);
        // filterModel.Term ?? String.Empty
        var term = Expression.Constant(filterModel.Term ?? String.Empty);
        //StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
        var comparison = Expression.Constant(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        //T p => p.ColumnName.StartsWith(filterModel.Term ?? String.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        var methodCall = Expression.Call(name, startsWith, term, comparison);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(methodCall, parameter);

        return input.Where(lambda.Compile())
        .Skip((filterModel.Page - 1) * filterModel.Limit)
        .Take(filterModel.Limit);
    }
}
```

Now this assumes that the column is of type string. Any other type would cause this to throw an exception.

You would also need to assume that `p` is not `null` else again a null reference exception will be thrown when trying to call instance members on a null reference.

Sample unit test of the extension method in use

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass2 {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod() {
        //Arrange
        IEnumerable<Person> persons = new List<Person>() {
            new Person() { Name = "Nancy Davolio", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1948-12-08"), Email = "nancy.davolio@test.com" },
            new Person() { Name = "Andrew Fuller", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1952-02-19"), Email = "andrew.fuller@test.com" },
            new Person() { Name = "Janet Leverling", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1963-08-30"), Email = "janet.leverling@test.com" },
            new Person() { Name = "Margaret Peacock", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1937-09-19"), Email = "margaret.peacock@test.com" },
            new Person() { Name = "Steven Buchanan", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1955-03-04"), Email = "steven.buchanan@test.com" },
            new Person() { Name = "Michael Suyama", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1963-07-02"), Email = "michael.suyama@test.com" },
            new Person() { Name = "Robert King", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1960-05-29"), Email = "robert.king@test.com" },
            new Person() { Name = "Laura Callahan", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1958-01-09"), Email = "laura.callahan@test.com" },
            new Person() { Name = "Anne Dodsworth", DOB = DateTime.Parse("1966-01-27"), Email = "anne.dodsworth@test.com" }
        };

        var filter = new FilterModel {                
            Term = "Nancy"
        };

        //Act
        var data = persons.FilterData("Name", filter);

        //Assert
        data.Should().NotBeEmpty();
    }
}
```